# sending images to Postgres using express/multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, multer

so I am using postman to send images to a post route via express library. I get the buffer of binary stuff out of it and it doesnt allows me to handle stuff. Using body-parser would help anyway?

this is where I upload the file:

```
app.post('/uploads', upload.single('upload'), async (req, res) => {
    const imgBuffer = req.file.buffer
    console.log(imgBuffer.toString())
    // await client.query('UPDATE rooms SET room = $1', [imgBuffer])
    res.send()
})
```

this is the output I have after fire the request on postman:

[image]

this wont allow me to store anything on postgres. Well, I saw that using base64 would be better to store... I really dont know. could someone help please?

Comment: You can store with base64; but often the better option is to store the image on disk, and just store a reference to the path/filename in the database.

Comment: ok, but how can i convert this buffer to base64?

Comment: converting buffer to string requires encoding

Comment: `var imgData = Buffer.from('abc')'; imgData === Buffer.from(imgData.toString('base64'), 'base64').toString() // true`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but did you search on this

new Buffer(data).toString('base64')